# AJAX POST with datatables not working (using ajax loaded)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, datatables

I'm trying to do this example https://datatables.net/blog/2017-03-31 everything works except the ajax request, the problem is that I'm trying to return data from a database and a barely know how to do it with ajax (newbie) this is how my code and ajax request look:

```
var id = 0;
$('#tablanormal tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var tdi = tr.find("i.fa");
            var row = table.row(tr);
            id = 0;
            id = parseInt(table.row(this).data().id_sol);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
                tdi.first().removeClass('fa-minus-square');
                tdi.first().addClass('fa-plus-square');
            } else {
                // Open this row
                row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
                tdi.first().removeClass('fa-plus-square');
                tdi.first().addClass('fa-minus-square');
            }
        });

        table.on("user-select", function (e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
            if ($(cell.node()).hasClass("details-control")) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

    function format(rowData) {
        var div = $('<div/>')
                .addClass('loading')
                .text('Loading...');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'datatables_ajax/items.php',
            data: {idsol: id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                div
                        .html(json.html)
                        .removeClass('loading');
            },
            error: function (er) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        });

        return div;
    }
```

item.php file

```
<?php

include_once '../datatables_ajax/conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

$idsol = $_POST['idsol'];   
$consulta = "CALL Items('".$idsol."')";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$resultado->execute();
$data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;"><tbody>'; 
foreach(['ID','item','number'] as $attribute) {
    echo '<tr><th>'.$attribute.'</th>';
    foreach($data as $row) {
        echo '<td>'.$row[$attribute].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
$conexion=null;
?>
```

items.php returns id_sol, item_name, item_number I wanted to return it first as text(it works if you only open the file) but the table just stay in "Loading..." when trying to show it, also it would be helpful if someone help me to return that data as a table.

Comment: I believe you have forgotten to pass the id  -> `row.child(format(row.data(), id)).show()`  and `function format(rowData, id) { `...You use id later on in the AJAX call.

Comment: I edit my code to show where "id" come from, also I just notice but to this to work, in the example they used RowData in data in the ajax code, but in my case, I'm using it for the POST method, so RowData is unused, and for real no idea how to change that.

Answer (score 1):

**First**

you should remove the loading text when the ajax call is complete that's inside the `complete: function(){}` not inside the `success: function(){}`.

**Second**

you can return the data as a table from PHP like this:

```
if ($resultado->rowCount()){ //meaning if the request returned some data
    $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $d = [];
  $i = ;
  foreach($data as $val){
    $d[i]['fieldName'] = $val['columnName'];
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}else{ //no data returned
//error handling here
}
```

**Third**

if you want to return the data as an HTML table then do this:

```
if ($resultado->rowCount()){ //meaning if the request returned some data
 $data=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $output = "
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>first header </th>
      <th>second header </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <body>
 ";
     $d = [];
     $i = ;
     foreach($data as $val){
      $output .=" 
       <tr>
       <td>first header data=".$val[columnName]."</td>
       <td>second header data=".$val[columnName]."</td>
       </tr>";

        $d[i]['fieldName'] = $val['columnName'];
      }
      $output .="  </tbody>
      </table>";
      echo json_encode($output);
    }else{ //no data returned
    //error handling here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I already manage to create the table (edited the post while you were probably writing this my bad), now I'm only having problems with the ajax part, I'll try adding the success part, and as I say in another answer,  in the example they used RowData in data in the ajax code, but in my case, I'm using it for the POST method, so RowData is unused, and for real no idea how to change that.

Comment: can you show me the example you're talking about, please?